# How do I find more than one occurence and replace using str?

Tags: c, strstr

My homework assignment is to read a file, store in target words (delimited by #) and replacement words (also delimited by #) and original strings (they do not have #).

Also I could not assume max str length, or max # of words.

For example:

```
#uic#e# // uic = target string   e = replacement string
juice  // find substring "uic"  and replace it with 'e' resulting in "jee"
quicken  // qeken
quiche   // qehe
uicuicuick // eeek
#pp##   // pp = target string   nothing = replacement string
apples  //ales
copper  // coer
bopped  //boed
#t#tttttt#  // t = target string   tttttt = replacement string
tut tut // ttttttutttttt ttttttutttttt
tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt // last string = 
                                                 //# of t's * 6
```

---

I've done EVERYTHING besides figuring out how to use the target string w/the replacement string. Is it possible to do it with `strstr`? I know it points to the first occurrence but is it possible to make it point to every occurrence in a string? Please show me using pseudocode. Thank you!

Comment: "Please show me using pseudocode" - Nope. You need to that AND write some code...

Comment: Show us your code (just saw your edit).

Comment: I'm not asking for the assignment. I'm asking if it's possible to point to another occurrence using strstr and if it is can someone show me pseudocode for it.

Answer (score 0):

Using strstr() to find the address of the first occurrence, call it `address`, then you could use strstr() again on `address + strlen(target_string)` to find the occurrences in the rest of the string.